# Is there a way to see a list of meteor releases I can update to?

Tags: meteor

I'm eagerly following the coming Cordova support, and see various release versions to update to in the docs-  examples:

```
meteor update --release CORDOVA-PREVIEW@3
meteor update --release CORDOVA-PREVIEW@5
meteor update --release METEOR@0.9.2-rc0
meteor update --release METEOR@0.9.2-rc2
```

Additionally, the [Meteor Cordova Wiki Page](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration) doesn't even mention a version.

What command can I run or page can I look at to see what 'the latest' Meteor 0.9.2 release candidate is ? And should I be updating from the 0.9.2 branch for the best Cordova support ?

Comment: All releases are listed at [meteors github page](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/) (click on the branch button/dropdown and select tags (each release has a unique tag)). Though, I don't know anything about Cordova, so I can't say if you should search for `0.9.2` or `CORDOVA`.

Comment: I found that the following works: `meteor update --release METEOR@0.9.2-rc8`, where the release is everything following `release` in the output of `git ls-remote --tags https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git tags/release/METEOR@0.9.2*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meteor tags releases in its git repository. You can use `git ls-remote` to check what tags are available. For example,

```
$ git ls-remote --tags https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git tags/release/METEOR@0.9.2*
3df58956e1656ade890ef3bc3821c97f842987b6        refs/tags/release/METEOR@0.9.2-rc0
3decef135ad453837104fff0562226e63d681442        refs/tags/release/METEOR@0.9.2-rc1
fb3fb5de03650b24e5aebb91d934119a075df791        refs/tags/release/METEOR@0.9.2-rc2
3f680f76a422107c25f1934b8ccb6fd9aee1b471        refs/tags/release/METEOR@0.9.2-rc3
63381e5ee4f52062c6ba5c0f271e88efd7f59c36        refs/tags/release/METEOR@0.9.2-rc4
52d66644e9d23a92c0905d2b5ba28b1e403ef691        refs/tags/release/METEOR@0.9.2-rc5
5fae8faeb06259c96566469ef14e181c78cea07b        refs/tags/release/METEOR@0.9.2-rc6
```

I guess you'd then run `meteor update` with one of those.

Comment: Thanks for much win in this answer!

Comment: Additionally, to monitor the latest meteor 1.2 RC:  `$(curl -sL http://bit.ly/latest-meteor-12-rc | sh)`

Answer (score 0):

I always check the following web-link to check **List of latest Meteor Releases** in Github:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/releases

Hope this helps :-)